# No imprime mis form en html,python,flask

Tags: html, mysql, python, sql, flask

> Intento imprimir mis imputs que estan dentro de un form,pero al cargar la application.py y acceder a la ruta /register(register.html), se ve el header,pero el body donde esta el form con los imputs,que intento enviar a la base de datos sqlite3, aparece vacio. Adjunto codigo de register.html,layout.html y application.py

register.html

```
      {% extends "layout.html" %}

  {% block body %}
        <h1>Registrants forms</h1>
         <form action="/register" method="post">
          <imput type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
          <imput type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Adress">
          <imput type="submit">
         </form>

 {% endblock %}
```

layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Registrants</title>
    </head>

    <body>
       {% block body %}
       {% endblock %}
    </body>



</html>
```

**Y este es mi codigo de python con las rutas:**

```
from cs50 import SQL
from flask import Flask,redirect, render_template, request

app=Flask(__name__)

db = SQL("sqlite:///lecture.db")

@app.route("/")
def index():
    rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM registrants")
    return render_template("index.html", rows=rows)

@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("register.html")
    else:
        name = request.form.get("name")
        email = request.form.get("email")
        db.execute("INSERT INTO registrants (name, email) VALUES (:name, :email)", name=name, email=email)
        return redirect("/")
```

**No logro encontrar el fallo en mi codigo!**

**Y esto me imprime el html,sin los imputs:**

[image: Lo que me imprime la web]

Comment: Hola Antonio, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor no coloques nunca código o errores como imágenes, dificultan la lectura especialmente en dispositivos móviles, entorpecen mucho la reproducción del código al no poder copiar y pegar y por último no indizan para futuras búsquedas. Agrega ésto siempre como texto, las imágenes solo deben ser accesorias si aclaran algo, por ejemplo la última. .

Comment: @FJSevilla Hola,intenté insertar el codigo pero no se porque,el codigo de python no me lo mostraba, y respecto al <form>, en la primera foto dentro de <body> esta puesto el <form> con los 3 <imputs>, y en herramientas de desarrollador en el codigo sí aparece,pero con un valor vacio,y no se donde esta el fallo

Comment: No uses snippets, son solo para HTML/JS/CSS, simplemente copia y pega el código y luego lo selecionas todo y pulsas Ctrl + k o el botón {} del editor para que se formatee como código. Aún así, si tienes problemas con el formateo tu pegalo y dejalo como puedas, seguro que alguien edita la pregunta y lo corrige.

Comment: @FJSevilla Modificado,gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes un error en el nombre de los tags de tu formulario:

```html
    <h1>Registrants forms</h1>
    <form action="/register" method="post">
        <imput type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
        <imput type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Adress">
        <imput type="submit">
    </form>
```

El tag HTML no es `imput`, debería ser `input`:

```html
    <h1>Registrants forms</h1>
    <form action="/register" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Adress">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```